# Catch event from inherit contract

Tags: solidity

I have simple contract who inherits ERC1155 and right now i'm adding some unit tests. However when I call my function to execute `_mint` I'm expecting to catch the event `"Transfer"` how ever i receive this msg:

`AssertionError: Expected event "Transfer" to be emitted, but it doesn't exist in the contract. Please make sure you've compiled its latest version before running the test`

and here is how my function looks like which is executed successfully:

```
function redeem(address _redeemer, NFTVoucher calldata _voucher) public payable returns (uint256) {
        require(startingAt < block.timestamp, "Not started");
        require(totalSupply[_voucher.tokenId] < _voucher.maxSupply, "Limit reached");

        address signer = _verify(_voucher);

        require(hasRole(MINTER_ROLE, signer), "Signature invalid or unauthorized");

        require(msg.value >= _voucher.minPrice, "Insufficient funds to redeem");

        idToUri[_voucher.tokenId] = _createUri(_voucher.uri);

        _mint(signer, _voucher.tokenId, 0, "");

        _mint(_redeemer, _voucher.tokenId, 1, "");

        return _voucher.tokenId;
    }
```

and here is how my test looks like:

```
it("should redeem successfully", async function () {
    await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [3600]);
    await network.provider.send("evm_mine");

    const [_, minter] = await ethers.getSigners();

    expect(
      await this.collection.redeem(minter.address, this.voucher, {
        value: this.voucher.minPrice,
      }),
    ).to.emit(this.collection, "Transfer");
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems fine.

I believe you are listening to the wrong event, [ERC-1555](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC1155/IERC1155.sol) has the following  events:

- TransferSingle
- TransferBatch

[_mint](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol#L260) emits the TransferSingle event, try changing your code to :

```
 expect(
      await this.collection.redeem(minter.address, this.voucher, {
        value: this.voucher.minPrice,
      }),
    ).to.emit(this.collection, "TransferSingle");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot yeah my bad wrong Event name, once again thanks a'lot!